# removing files from ec2 server

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have installed rails with Nginx in EC2 server.Now I want to remove all the installed application from that.So for removing all of them I am using sudo apt-get remove --purge .But some times the files are not being removed.So how can I do that.I have only user access.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to get root access (which is the default access you get when you create an EC2 instance, so someone in your organization should have it).  Removing packages requires root.

Comment: ..even though the OP is using 'sudo' ?